# Python mysql fetchall() returns additional characters

Tags: python, mysql, fetchall

I am trying to retrieve values from a table to use in a calculation. The code below

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SELECT number FROM info")

rows = mycursor.fetchall()

print (rows)
```

This returns this list

```
[(Decimal('30.00'),), (Decimal('66.00'),), (Decimal('72.00'),)]
```

How can I retrieve the numerical value only either in a list or tuple like

```
[30.00, 66.00, 72.00]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original data type in `mydb` might be a Decimal object.
So you can cast the datatype in the MySQL query or python code.

1) Case in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT CAST(number AS DOUBLE) FROM info
```

but this code returns the fetched rows as 
`[(30.00,), (66.00,), (72.00,)]` because the tuples represent the columns of the query result.

2) Case in python code:

```py
converted_rows = list(map(lambda row:float(row[0]), rows))
```

It will return `[30.00, 66.00, 72.00]` list.